# How to show a input value in the same page in laravel using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, input

Im trying show de year that the user put in the input with the id 'searchBar' and show it on the lable with the 'outp' id in the table on the same laravel page with javascript.
But its just not working..

Heres my show.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-2">
                        <form action="" method="GET" role="search">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="seachBar" name="q" placeholder="Search year">                              
                                <button type="submit" id="btn"></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-2">

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-left" style="width: 5%">Data</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr scope="row">
                                        <td class="text-left">31/01/<lable id="outp"></p></td>
                                    </tr>
```

i have already connected the javascipt file with this:

`<script src="{{ asset('js/showYear.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and this is my javascript file showYear.js :

```
var year = document.getElementById('seachBar').value;


document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function showYear(year)
{
document.getElementById('outp').innerHTML = year; 
}
```

im new to laravel and javascript i started maybe 2 to 3 weeks ago on my intership  so im kinda lost :) .
help would be great,  tkx

Comment: Do you want `onkeyup` value ??

Comment: `showYear(year){ }` the first argument passed to event listener functions is the `event` object. If you want to get the year from the input put that line of code inside the event listener function  Also since your button is inside a `<form>` you either need to prevent the default submit action (as the page will navigate away) or change its `type` to `button`

Comment: The first line of your JavaScript file will only run exactly once, and will not magically extend into the future. To read the actual current value you need to read it *inside* the handler function: https://jsfiddle.net/chxfpqtz/ (I also fixed your invalid HTML; in case you are not using an IDE like VS Code or Netbeans or what have you I'll definitely recommend doing so)

Comment: Is the code `var year = document.getElementById('seachBar').value;` inside some onload function? if not, it will be triggered on load, which means that it will get the value of the input before the user have had a chance to write anything. You should get values when you need them. At least when it's inputs that the user might change.

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#seachBar").keyup(function() {
    $("#outp").html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-2">
<form action="" method="GET" role="search">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="seachBar" name="q" placeholder="Search year">                              
<button type="submit" id="btn">Submit</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-2">

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-left" style="width: 5%">Data</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr scope="row">
        <td class="text-left" id="outp"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```